# Power Cycle Cisco MDS 9506

Tags: cisco, storage, switch, storage-area-network

Would someone walk me through the steps to power cycle a Cisco MDS 9506 FC switch?  It would help if you would provide a link to relevant documentation for this procedure. I must perform a power maintenance related outage this weekend and I want to make sure I have all the steps handy.

What would be the CLI command I need to execute for this to take effect?

Answer (score 3):

If you've written your config to flash and your hosts are 'expecting' the outage then you can just physically switch the PSUs off or issue a 'reload' command via SSH, serial etc. To power it one, well...power on the PSUs.

If you've not written your config to flash, do that.

Comment: Hi chopper3 - a quick question :To copy the startup-config to flash as a file say backupconfig, we can use the command:"copy startup-config flash:backupconfig" My question is how should i set up the backupconfig file?  Plus, servers will be brought down as well

Comment: that command would create the backupconfig file, you don't need to set it up

Comment: Thanks, Say if have to retrieve it at some point , where and how can this be done?basically, where should i be looking for this file to retrieve , is there a similar command to do this like creating?

Comment: you'd just use the same copy command to copy it to a different name, it's just a min file system

Answer (score 2):

1) make sure config is saved
2) remove plug
3) re-insert plug

Comment: Thanks zypher ..can you please describe a little more , or if there a good doc i can go through? I will be doing this for the first time..so  any help would be appreciated? Like the cLI command.

Comment: what code version are you on?